# count duplicate strings and place number at the start of the output file

Tags: windows, perl, duplicates, ubuntu-11.10

what command with perl would allow me to count lines?
in the output file should be at the start of the line how many times the contiguous lines appeared in a previous sorted file used as input.

input example :

```
line 1
line 2
line 2
line 2
line 3
line 3
line 3
```

ouput:

```
1= line 1
3= line 2
3= line 3
```

Comment: What about `uniq -c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne '$c{$_}++; END {print "$c{$_}= $_" for keys %c}' your_file
```

If you'd like to stream the results for a sorted file so that it stays in order and isn't loaded entirely into memory:

```
perl -ne 'if (defined $l && $l ne $_) {print "$c= $l"; $c=0} $l=$_;$c++; END{print "$c= $l"}' your_file
```

Comment: thanks that worked, is there a way to output the result into a file?

Comment: last modification keeps order, looks nicer.

Comment: Yep, that's why I added it, thought it might be preferred.